# HttpClient and proxy with Windows 8 Store application

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, dotnet-httpclient

We are creating a Windows Store application (WinRT) line of business application is to be installed on computers that are in a network that requires them use a proxy to connect to the internet.  My assumption is that the HttpClient uses the proxy information set in IE.  Is this a true statement?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: From the MSDN documentation, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.defaultwebproxy.aspx, it states that web proxy information first from the App.config and if not present, from the IE.  Anyone have any experience with this. Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN documentation [HttpClientHandler.Proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.proxy.aspx):

> If no proxy is specified in a config file and the Proxy property is unspecified, the handler uses the proxy settings inherited from Internet Explorer on the local computer.